# Date format change To UTC

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have getting a dateformat like '23.10.2017'. I need to format this in to

'10/23/2017'

I just tried

```
var crDate='23.10.2017';
var newDateF=new Date(crdate).toUTCString();
```

but it showing InvalidDate

can anyone help to change the format.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: `var [day, month, year] = "23.10.2017".split(".");(new Date(year, month, day)).toUTCString()`

Comment: `'10/23/2017'`  That's not a UTC Date..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using `Date()` is the solution. You can do

```
var crDate = '23.10.2017';
var newDateF = crDate.split(".");
var temp = newDateF[0];
newDateF[0] = newDateF[1];
newDateF[1] = temp;
newDateF.join("/");
```

This splits the string into an array, swaps the first and second elements, and then joins back on a slash.

Answer (score 1):

A regex replacement will do the trick without any `Date` functions.

```js
var date = '23.10.2017';
var regex = /([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})/;
console.log(date.replace(regex,'$2/$1/$3'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) if you can :

```
// convert a date from/to specific format
moment("23.10.2017", "DD.MM.YYYY").format('MM/DD/YYYY')

// get the current date in a specific format
moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Moment is a very usefull and powerfull date/time library for Javascript.